# Why can't I access my file in VS 2013 with TFS

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2013

Having problems with Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio where a file is in the project, but I'm getting a Check Out error saying that it either can't access the file or I don't have permission to do so.

Neither of which is true, I've checked the security settings on the file properties and they're the same on Service1.cs as everything else within the project.

Has anyone had the same/similar experience and know how to resolve this occurrence?

Picture for situation clarity:

[image]

Second, more clear image of Solution Explorer.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those files exist in source control, do a get latest to bring down the file into your work space.

Remove the files from the source control and check in to TFS to remove the discrepancy.

Add the files back into the solution through the SC and check in, this should solve the issue and stop the error message. The solution explorer/source control/TFS will also all acknowledge that the files are there.

Answer (score 1):

Because you doing copy paste service1.cs file. You service1.cs file right click and than Include Form Project Click

Comment: I've excluded and then included from the Solution Explorer if that's what you mean?

Comment: You should do included item. and then build project. And CheckIn TFS